# Scrapy logs says pages crawled but 0 objects found. When done with scrapy shell it works but when i am exporting the results this happens

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping [this](https://forums.pubg.com/leaderboard/) i have scraped this link for different fields differently but as soon as i do it in a scrapy project nothing works.

This is my code of spider file:

```
import scrapy
from pubg.items import MemberItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst

class Pubg_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="pubgspider"
    start_urls = ["https://forums.pubg.com/leaderboard/"]

    def parse(self, response):

        job_list =response.css('div.row')

        for job in job_list:
            job_loader = ItemLoader(MemberItem(), selector=job)
            job_loader.default_output_processor=TakeFirst()
            job_loader.add_css('Upload_Date','time::text')
            job_loader.add_css('Source','.ipsType_reset.ipsStreamItem_title.ipsContained.ipsType_break > a::attr(href)')
            job_loader.add_css('Headline','.ipsType_reset.ipsStreamItem_title.ipsContained.ipsType_break > a::text')
            job_loader.add_css('Content','.ipsType_richText.ipsContained.ipsType_medium > div > div::text')
            job_loader.add_css('Vote','.cPopularItem_stats.ipsType_center::text')
            yield job_loader.load_item()
```

My pipeline file looks like this:

```
class PubgPipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        item['Upload_Date']
    except KeyError:
        item['Upload_Date'] = 'N/A'
    try:
        item['Source']
    except KeyError:
        item['Source'] = 'N/A'
    try:
        item['Headline']
    except KeyError:
        item['Headline'] = 'N/A'
    try:
        item['Content']
        item['Content']=''.join(c for c in item['Content'] if c not in '\r\t\n')
    except KeyError:
        item['Content'] = 'N/A'
    try:
        item['Vote']
        item['Vote']=''.join(c for c in item['Vote'] if c not in '\r\t\n')
    except KeyError:
        item['Vote'] = 'N/A'
    return item
```

I am a beginner in both scrapy and stackoverflow so do mention any mistakes.

Comment: Please elaborate on "nothing works". Do you have some logs of what doesn't work (selectively, anonymized is ok)?

Comment: @nyov the console shows that pages are crawled but I am exporting the feed to a CSV file but I don't get any results stored in it.

Comment: That could be any number of configuration issues. Does the `loader.load_item()` have data? does the Pipeline show the item? (Run with DEBUG loglevel to see yielded items in the log). FeedExporters and ItemPipelines are exclusive, I believe. Use `CsvItemExporter` instead. -- https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.logger.debug(<string or variable>)` from spider methods, or `spider.logger.debug()` from spider pipeline methods.

For more information, see [Debugging Spiders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html).